# Kotlin "when in range" not working for negative numbers

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm passing -3.0 (Hard coded for my testing purpose) to "when" conditions here result was always comes zero (0 - execute else statement).

Positive numbers working fine, Negative numbers comes that time only not working

Below I'm shared screenshots for reference.

[image]

Comment: Look at your code and think youself where will `-3.05` go?

Comment: -3.05 goes to else statement - It is correct.  I'm passing -3.0 but same else statement execute.

Comment: Use `-3.0..-2.1` instead of `-2.1..-3.0` (and same for the other negative ranges). The smaller number should be the starting number. That fixes the problem when I tried it. Also, for future questions, do not post images of code. Just copy-paste the code into the question, and then format it into a code block. That makes it much easier for people to copy your code onto their own computers to test things out, which means you're more likely to get help.

Comment: @Slaw Working fine and also thanks for your suggestion, I'll do it in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/d8b0dbe71bbeb84ba0fbdac87801c8c6f4eed4c9/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/ranges/Ranges.kt#L49:%7E:text=override%20fun%20contains(value%3A%20Double)%3A%20Boolean%20%3D%20value%20%3E%3D%20_start%20%26%26%20value%20%3C%3D%20_endInclusive) of `ClosedDoubleRange.contains` is

```
override fun contains(value: Double): Boolean = value >= _start && value <= _endInclusive
```

if `start` is larger than `endInclusive`, it always return false. So for negative range, you should write
`in -3.0..-2.1`